# Can a dragonborn use his breath weapon as a weapon attack if he is hasted?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attack, dragonborn, breath-weapon

Let's say im a level 5 fighter dragonborn, and I have the potion of haste. Then I have one extra attack, action surge, and a breath weapon. Under the description of the potion of haste, it says you can take one additional action, and take the attack action if you only make **1** weapon attack, but does fire breath count as a weapon attack?
Specifically, can I first drink the potion as a bonus action, then use my action to attack twice, then use action surge to attack twice more, *then use fire breath* as a third action allowed by the potion of haste?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Fire Breath is not a valid use of Haste

Haste specifically says...

> That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

[Source](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/haste)

The Dragonborn Race's breath weapon says...

> You can use your action to exhale destructive energy.

[Source](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/dragonborn)

Thus, to use your Breath Weapon, you are taking the "Use Breath Weapon" Action.

"Use Breath Weapon" is a separate Action from the "Attack" Action. The Attack Action is...

> With this action, you make one melee or ranged attack.
>
> Certain features, such as the Extra Attack feature of the fighter, allow you to make more than one attack with this action.

[Source](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Attack)

This is the sort of Attack that Haste allows you to use...with the caveat that you only get to make 1 attack (cannot use Multiattack)

I can understand where the confusion comes from, as the Dragonborn's Breath Attack is called a "Breath Weapon," but that is a coincidence of naming.

Answer (score 12):

## No.

Looking at the wording of *haste* it says that you must use an Attack action, which can be one ranged or one melee attack. The racial Breath Weapon trait uses your action, meaning it can not be used as part of the Attack action. You could strike twice, action surge breath weapon, *haste* strike once.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have been looking into the interaction between Dragons Breath the spell and Find Familiar so it was on my mind.

Answer (score 0):

## You cannot use it for the additional *Hasted* action.

**The key thing to check is does the Breath Weapon count as an attack under the rules?**

The answer to this question lies in the [Making an Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack) section of the basic rules where it states:

> If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you're making an attack roll, you're making an attack.

The [Breath Weapon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/races#Dragonborn) doesn't make an attack roll, it forces the people in the way to make a saving throw.

> When you use your breath weapon, each creature in the area of the exhalation must make a saving throw, the type of which is determined by your draconic ancestry.

Therefore it is not an attack and it is invalid for use in your *Hasted* action.

**What combinations are permissible with Haste for attacking?**

You have, however mentioned that you have a regular action and your action surge.

[Action Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/classes#ActionSurge) states:

> On your turn, you can take one additional action on top of your regular action and a possible bonus action.

So you can use that *Action Surge* action to use your Breath Weapon. Finally, you can, of course, use your regular action to use your Breath Weapon.

So the list of agressive actions you can make in a single round is:

- Action: 2 attacks
- Action Surge Action: 2 attacks
- Hasted Action: 1 attack

or

- Action: 2 attacks
- Action Surge Action: Breath Weapon
- Hasted Action: 1 attack

or

- Action: Breath Weapon
- Action Surge Action: 2 attacks
- Hasted Action: 1 attack

Comment: In fact, whether the breath weapon usage is an attack is entirely irrelevant. The Breath Weapon trait tells you that "You can use your action to exhale destructive energy." Its description of this as taking an action - without mentioning the Attack action, or describing it as casting a spell - means that it is its own, separate action, unrelated to the Attack action, the Cast a Spell action, or any other defined action. Even if it said, "You can use your action to spit fire as an attack" and described the rolls, it still wouldn't be the Attack action - unless it explicitly said it was.

Comment: (That's in response to your first section.)

Comment: @V2Blast I'm making the more general point that if you want to argue something is an attack from the perspective of the game (small a), then an attack roll is required. Since this does not require an attack roll, then it isn't an attack, and the Haste rule specifically limits you to an attack.

Comment: For example a wild shaped, polymorphed, shapchanged, or true polymorphed PC could have access to the MultiAttack action, under which they are still making attacks. In that form they can still choose to use the regular Attack action and choose only one of the forms attacks should they be under the effect of the Haste spell (as a hypothetical) (or in the case of wild shape if they have access to a class feature that enables them to attack more than once with the Attack action)

Comment: Haste specifically limits you to (among other options) the Attack action, not simply any attack. It then further that limits that Attack action to include a single weapon attack - but if the action you're trying to do isn't the Attack action, then you can't do it regardless of whether it consists of an attack or not.

Comment: @V2Blast if something is defined in the game as an attack it qualifies for use under the Attack action, as the only qualifier required under the Attack action is that you make a melee or ranged attack.

Comment: The point I was making with the MultiAttack example is that the MultiAttack action is a special action monsters get access to, which allow them to make multiple attacks. It does not preclude them instead from using the Attack action (which they also have access to) and attack with their natural weapons (ala claws) or their actual weapons (ala daggers) under the Attack action